# Recording audio and sending data in real time through bluetooth on raspberry pi zero

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, pybluez

I am trying to record audio on raspberry pi zero and want to transfer the audio data in real time through Bluetooth (Classic or BLE) to an android application . I have created a GATT server referring to Bluez example code but given the amount of data(32-bit audio data, 16000 Hz). The process through BLE is really slow and i am not able to record and send the data simultaneously but one by one.
So i want to shift to Bluetooth Classic. What would be the preferable protocol where i can record and send the data along as soon as i receive it ? Are there Pybluez API which can allow me to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using Pyaudio to record through I2S MEMS Microphone. I am using flutter_blue for connecting my raspberry pi through ble to my android application. On Raspberry pi, i am using Bluez example code for GATT Server which communicates through Dbus objects. I want to send the data as soon as i get it from my microphone, without playing on raspberry pi . And my Android application would upload it on firebase

Comment: Audio data streaming from source to sink, you should A2DP profile's source role. Usually Android phone is also source device, so you should sink device. U should enable sink role in Android phone.